# Venn diagram using flex or action script

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

My requirement goes like this.I need to create a venn diagram in flex or action script.I need to create 2 circles.Let's say two circles,circle A and circle B. Both circles should have different color and intersected(A^B).so, finally it should have three colors.circle A,circle B and the intersection part respectively.After that, when i click circle A,only circle A part(excluding intersection part) should be highlighted and remaining should be the same.When i click intersection part,only that intersection part(A^B) should be highlighted and circle A should get the initial color as it was.similar case with tha circle B.I have done all trail n errors using sprite,bit map and degrafa swc also.But im not able to meet the exact requirement. Brilliant brains please get me out of this.

Comment: Do the circles need to be generated dynamically?  Or can this be a statically defined drawing?

Comment: yes Brian, the circles will be generated dynamically and will be intersected.After that,if i click, the colors should change

Answer (score 0):

As of now the circles can be statically created.But i need the functionality which i have mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

It should just be a single object with 3 parts, rather than two intersecting circles.

You can then have 4 states (unselected, A, B, AB ) for each selected piece.

That's pretty straightforward.

Comment: its not a single circle.i need to show 2 different circles which are intersected.when i click,it should do the above mentioned functionality.

Comment: I didn't say single circle, I said single object. You don't actually have 2 circles which intersect, you have an irregular shape for A, and irregular shape for b, and a pointed oval for the intersection. These are three parts of the overall shape. It'll make your requirements much easier to fufill.

Comment: Hi Gregor,Circles will be dynamically created.Actually in my requirement i have 3 to 4 circles.The parameters for creating circles will be coming from some xml.so i need to take payload from that xml and pass it for getting circles.After that when i click,colors should be highlighted according to the parts intersected

Comment: What's your XML like? Is it specifying coordinates, or just that A intersects B...